# @InitBinder restricting to single validator

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In  my controller, when I set a validator to the webdatabinder:

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

My controller only applies that validator and ignore other fields' validation:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void processRecord(@Valid @RequestBody Record record, Errors errors) {
    //code
}
```

The field validation ignored are annotation based:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 60, message="firstName must be between 2 and 60 characters long.")
private String firstName;
```

Is there a way to add the custom validator and still apply the default annotation based validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a custom validator does indeed override the default ones.

There is a need to inject a basic validator on top of the custom one:

```
    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.replaceValidators(validator, basicValidator);
    }
```

The `@Autowired` basic validator being declared as follow:

```
    @Bean
    public Validator basicValidator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```